# Javascript continuously refresh page asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a dashboard webpage which is loaded on the TV. This page want to refresh once per second.

**The first approach I tried is nice and simple and respects standards:**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
```

This creates a nasty flashing effect in Mac / Chrome and iOS / Safari which is unacceptable.

**The next version works great... the content is loaded and presented with no visible interruption:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "",
    context: document.body,
    success: function(s,x){
        $(this).html(s);
    }
  });
}, 2000);
</script>
```

And this works great... the content is loaded and presented with no visible interruption. However this will crash any browser (IE, Chrome, Safari, Mobile Safari) after several minutes.

Is there a way solve this problem that does not require me to maintain two separate pages the, reloading part and the inside data part?

Comment: Can you determine the reason for the browser to crash? A likely culprit is that the memory used by the page is continually going up. You could check that using the developer console.

Comment: do you really need to load the whole body? Are you also reloading the same polling script at the same time (and other scripts)?

Answer (score 2):

Use `timeout` to create a "polling" effect.. right now you just fire off a request every `2` seconds regardless of waiting for the response. Ideally you could use web-sockets for this, but for now:

```
function makeAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(s,x){
            $(this).html(s);
            setTimeout(makeAjax, 2000);
        }
    });
}
makeAjax();
```

Comment: With this approach you would create an Interval after every 2 sec

Comment: @Fuzzyma -- Ahh, meant `timeout` - long day. Edited.

Comment: When implementing this, I see requests coming faster and faster and then basically it is like a put a rock on the F5 key.